# mpd configuration [22.04 UbuntuStudio + KDE Plasma]

Tags: configuration, mpd

I think I need help. I tried and read everything around, still I have a problem in setting MPD properly. I installed/uninstalled several times (from tar.xz , git, apt-get) and I think I messed up the files.

1. One main problem is that apparently I have two places for mpd.conf:

**meson configure |grep sysconfdir**

> ```
>   sysconfdir           etc          Sysconf data directory
> ```

**mpd --no-daemon --stdout --verbose**

> config_file: loading file ~/.config/mpd/mpd.conf
> exception: Failed to bind to '[::1]:6600'; Failed to bind socket: Address already
> in use

2. I put the same config file in the two places, but still If I check:

> systemctl status mpd.service
>
> × mpd.service - Music Player Daemon
>
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/mpd.service; disabled;
> vendor preset: enabled)
>
> ```
>  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-09-21 21:58:49 WEST; 33s ago
>
>    Docs: man:mpd(1)
>
>          man:mpd.conf(5)
>
> Process: 11517 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mpd --systemd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> ```
>
> Main PID: 11517 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> CPU: 209ms
>
> set 21 21:58:49 rdw systemd[1]: Starting Music Player Daemon...
>
> set 21 21:58:49 rdw mpd[11517]: exception: No configuration file found
>
> set 21 21:58:49 rdw systemd[1]: mpd.service: Main process exited,
> code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>
> set 21 21:58:49 rdw systemd[1]: mpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>
> set 21 21:58:49 rdw systemd[1]: Failed to start Music Player Daemon.

while mpd and systemd files are here

/usr/local/bin/mpd
/usr/local/lib/systemd/

I tried to look around, but still I am not able to properly configure it!
any help?

many thanks,
R

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you suing? A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry if I missed this information, as this is the first time I try to configure MPD: I run now 22.04 Ubuntustudio + Kde Plasma